# Get m2m field (with through model) list in django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django 2.0.7.

I want to get all the fields of a model. I can get all the normal fields in:

```
model._meta.fields
```

And I can get m2m fields in:

```
model._meta.local_many_to_many
```

However, if the m2m field has an through table, I can't access them? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The m2m fields have a `through` model that you can access:

```
YourModel.m2m_field.through._meta.fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
model._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

Comment: the "get_all_field_names" method is not attribute of _meta......not in my version